# Define new socket option for use in TCP kernel code

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, tcp

I'm trying to add some functionality to the TCP kernel code (in **tcp_input.c**). I want the code I've implemented to run only in certain situations. I want to add a control flag, which can be set from a user-space application.

I (think I) need to add a new socket option, so that I can accomplish the following with `setsockopt()`.

**kernel space:**

```
if(tcp_flags.simulate_ecn_signal) {
  // run code for simulating ecn signal
}
```

**user space:**

```
if(tcp_info.tcpi_retransmits > LIMIT) {
  u8 simulate_ecn_signal = 1;

  // set the flag, so that the kernel code runs
  if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_FLAGS, &simulate_ecn_signal, sizeof(simulate_ecn_signal)) < 0)
    printf("Can't set data with setsockopt.\n");
}
```

*In the example code above I've added an example flag* `simulate_ecn_signal` *which I thought could be a member of a (new) socket option (struct) called* `tcp_flags` *(that potentially could contain multiple flag values).*

**How do I define a new socket option, in order to accomplish this?**

Comment: It seems to me that this migration was incorrect. The question requires knowledge of Linux internals which would surely be more concentrated where the question was originally posted.

Comment: @EJP: No. Unix.SE is for end users and systems administrators of these type of operating systems, not for programming questions about them. About the only time you see answers that dig into the kernel code over there is when someone is trying to expain why it is the way it is, often in an historical context. I support this migration.