# Use setsockopt() to modify kernel structures in TCP?

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, c, tcp

Is it possible to modify a single member of a kernel struct in TCP? I want to be able to use `setsockopt()` to update a member of the tcp_info struct in TCP.

I've tried the following:

```
struct tcp_info info;
unsigned int optlen = sizeof(struct tcp_info);

if (getsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_INFO, &info, &optlen) < 0)
  printf("Can't get data from getsockopt.\n");

info.retransmits += 10; // random member of tcp_info - as example

if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_INFO, (char *) &info, optlen) < 0)
  printf("Can't set data with setsockopt.\n");
```

The call to `setsockopt()` fails (returns a negative value).

The way I'm trying to solve it (above), *given that it had worked* - doesn't seem optimal. Is it possible to modify a members value from a struct, without having to fetch and update the entire struct (all of its members)?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. `TCP_INFO` is used to provide information about the socket to user space and is thus read-only. It thus makes no sense to call `setsockopt` with `TCP_INFO` and thus an error is returned if you try it.

Comment: I want to add a control statement in the TCP kernel code (tcp_input.c). My goal is to have a structure with members that would work as control variables in the kernel code, that can be enabled/disabled from an user space application with setsockopt (or some other function for interacting with the kernel). Here's an example of flag (I want): `tcp_flags.simulate_ecn_signal = 1;`

Comment: If you want to add new custom functionality to the kernel then you should define a *new* socket option, not shoehorn into an existing one that has a different meaning.

Comment: How to you define a new socket option? Is it sufficient to create a new structure in tcp.h (uapi/linux)?

Comment: @LarsErikStorbukås: your are moving away from your original question. Either  change it to reflect what you really want to do (since there is no answer yet) or ask a new one. In any case provide a detailed description of the overall problem you are trying to solve in the question instead of only the specific problem you had with your attempted solution. See also [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem),

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for your feedback. I've posted it as a new question (and updated this question with the edit), in order to avoid XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may not set arbitrary values with `setsockopt()`. It has a finite list of options you may set.

I'll use the FreeBSD kernel in this example, but all of this is similar if not identical in Linux.  I will jump to FreBSD's `sosetopt()` function in [`sys/kern/uipc_socket.c`](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/cb6abe87cf1c178ea1b9cd8a385e53459aef96e8/sys/kern/uipc_socket.c#L3030).

The only valid options you may set are:

```
SO_ACCEPTFILTER, SO_LINGER, SO_DEBUG, SO_KEEPALIVE, SO_DONTROUTE, SO_USELOOPBACK, SO_BROADCAST, SO_REUSEADDR, SO_REUSEPORT, SO_REUSEPORT_LB, SO_OOBINLINE, SO_TIMESTAMP, SO_BINTIME, SO_NOSIGPIPE, SO_NO_DDP, SO_NO_OFFLOAD, SO_RERROR, SO_SETFIB, SO_USER_COOKIE, SO_SNDBUF, SO_RCVBUF, SO_SNDLOWAT, SO_RCVLOWAT, SO_SNDTIMEO, SO_RCVTIMEO, SO_LABEL, SO_TS_CLOCK, and SO_MAX_PACING_RATE.
```

That list contain a number of status flags, enabling or disabling features. There are only a few that allow setting of numerical values.

- SO_USER_COOKIE - set a user-specified metadata value to a socket.
- SO_SNDBUF/SO_RCVBUF - set the allocated buffer sizes for sending and receiving.
- SO_SNDLOWAT/SO_RCVLOWAT - set a minimum amount of data to be sent/received per call.
- SO_SNDTIMEO/SO_RCVTIMEO - set a timeout for sending/receiving calls.
- SO_MAX_PACING_RATE - Instructs the network adapter to limit the transfer rate.

None of these write values directly to kernel structures. To accomplish something of the sort you have request, you will need to modify the kernel. Your [other question addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251928) that objective.